# Setup tab click listener in Firefox WebExtensions API

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I can get [tab objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab) via `browser.tabs.query`...

But how to setup an `onclick` listener on a tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently can't.

The relevant bug can be found here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246706 Allow listening for mouse events on tabs

Try implementing your addon in a different way if possible. You can add contextmenu items to the tab context, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/create and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/ContextType

To create a context menu for the tab context, use:

```
browser.menus.create({
  id: "your-menuitem-id",
  title: "Action on a tab",
  contexts: ["tab"]
});
```

Then you'd have to use the onClicked listener inside of a background script. Read the articles above to learn more.

Comment: Note that bug was marked as WONTFIX. So it's unlikely that this feature is going to exist in the future.